# How do I properly query a one-to-one rel in my Eloquent models?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `User` model, in which I have the following function:

```
public function employees()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Employee','userid');
    }
```

Then there is an `Employee` model, which has a function:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','userid');
    }
```

Now I want to implement this functionality, can I do this:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($user->id);
    $employee = $user->employees()->where('userid',$user->id)->get();
    $employeeStartDate = $employee->startdate;
```

Comment: Your relationship methods are plural, but you're defining **singular** relationships. Does a user have many employees and an employee can have many users? Can you post the database schema for both tables?

Comment: @Steve-Bauman Actually the relationships are supposed to be one - to - one. I watched a tutorial on laracasts and that's how he did it for one - to - many relationships. I'm unsure how to properly do it for one-to-one.

Comment: You setup the relationships properly for one to one, I was just confused as the naming conventions conflict with each other. You can just rename the methods to their singular versions (`employee`, `user`). Then call `$user = User::with('employee')->findOrFail($id);` Then retrieve the employee information using `$user->employee->start_date`.

Comment: @SteveBauman could you make that answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with one to one relationships, it'd be easier to understand your relationships if you renamed them to their singular versions (`employee()`, `user()`).

Then, you can load the relationship in your query using the `with()` method:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = User::with('employee')->findOrFail($id);

    $startDate = $user->employee->startdate;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$user = User::with('employees')->findOrFail($user->id);
dd($user->employees);
```

Or, since it's one-to-one relationship you could try this:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($user->id);
dd($user->employees());
```

Comment: This solution works as well with changes. The chosen answer is more in relation to my query.